# How to return xml data in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am working on postgresql function where i want to return a xml.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.func_name(
    ws_queue_array character varying DEFAULT NULL::character(1),
    OUT ws_out_xml_data xml)
          RETURNS xml
```

I am creating an xml using xml function in postgreql but I am not sure how will I return that xml.

```
SELECT  XMLELEMENT (NAME "name",                 
                   XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT(NAME "var1",                           
                             XMLATTRIBUTES (                                    
                          c_name        AS "c name",                         
                          c_id  AS "c ID"))                         
                     ORDER BY c_id ASC))              
                        INTO OUT_XML_DATA;
```

How do i return this `OUT_XML_DATA`?

Comment: Can you post the whole function? I guess you're just missing just the `RETURN OUT_XML_DATA` command in the end of your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS XML AS $BODY$
DECLARE output XML;
BEGIN 
SELECT '<foo bar="xyz"><abc/><!--test--><xyz/></foo>'::XML INTO output;
RETURN output;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_function();
```